# Vanity URLs with resources in other folders

Tags: php, apache, mod-rewrite

I want to create shorter links for my site, eg

```
site.come/u/1
```

instead of

```
site.com/user.php?u=1
```

I've had a play with `mod_rewrite` but quite honestly have no idea what I'm doing with it, I can create the url but when resources are being loaded on the page, they're being loaded from `/u/css/core.css` instead of `/css/core.css`

I'm loading in css/images/js with relative URLs, is there any way to make a rewrite rule exclude certain folders without having to change all of my code to absolute urls?

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you use absolute paths? If url rewriting works, it's not a `mod_rewrite` issue.

Comment: We have a few hundred lines of code, we could replace the paths but it's at the bottom of the priority list. The reason I'm asking about mod_rewrite is I want to know if there is a way to exclude a directory from being rewritten, for example, the css directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try with:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^(css|js|images)/.*$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [L]
```

And place it **before** any other rule.

I've tested it [here](http://htaccess.madewithlove.be) and it works!

Answer (score 1):

Well, you are pretty much answering your own question - instead of using relative path, you will need to use absolute path for your css.

Your browser now sees the page as www.site/u/user.php, i.e. you would need to use ../css/core.css. If your site is in the root, /css/core.css might suffice but it is much safer to use the full path (i.e. echo `$webpath."css/core.css"` where $wehpath will most likely be something like `$webpath="http://".$_SERVER["SERVER_NAME"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];`)

Comment: This is what I was trying to avoid but if it's the only solution, it'll have to do! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use absolute paths and everything will be fine.

For example you can do it like that:

```
<?php 
$baseURL = basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']); 
?>
<link href="<?php echo $baseURL; ?>/css/core.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```